# Checkbox checked not work when using an hidden div

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a dropdown (*lbProperty*), when the value selected value is 2, *div1* is show but the 2 last line with *textbox1* and *textbox2* are hidden. It's ok that's work.

When *div1* is show, there is no effect on the *check* event, I never see "Click!".

Any idea ?

Thanks,

**In the main page :**

```
@model DPI_MVC3Razor.Models.MyModel
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#div1').hide();

    $('#lbProperty').change(function () {
        var result = $(this).val();
        $('#div1').hide();
        if (result == 2)
            $('#div1').show();
    });

    if ($('#checkbox1').attr('checked')) {
        alert("Click!");
    }
});

<div id="div1">
    @Html.Partial("div1Content", Model)
</div>
```

---

**In "div1Content"**

```
@model DPI_MVC3Razor.Models.MyModel

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".jcsss1").hide();
    });
</script>

<table>
<tr>
    <td>AAAAA</td>
    <td>@Html.CheckBox("chk9", Model.IsOK)</td>       
</tr>
<tr class="jcsss1">
    <td>BBBBB</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBox("textbox1", Model.MyValue1)</td>
</tr>
<tr class="jcsss1">
    <td>CCCCC</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBox("textbox2", Model.MyValue2)</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't placed anything on the check event.

```
if ($('#checkbox1').attr('checked')) {
        alert("Click!");
    }
```

this code is only within `document.ready`, meaning it only executes once when the DOM finishes loading.

You want this:

```
$('#checkbox1').click(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
        alert("Click!");
    }
});
```